# Inline CSS statements for table <td/> in python

Tags: python, html, css, formatting, inline

I am facing an issue with viewing HTML emails and need to format the css to be inline with the HTML script.

I have the following td css used by multiple tables.

```css
td.gridtopleft {
  border-left: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  border-top: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridtopcent {
  border-top: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridtopright {
  border-right: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  border-top: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridmidleft {
  border-left: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridcenter {
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridmidright {
  border-right: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridbotleft {
  border-left: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  border-bottom: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridbotcent {
  border-bottom: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
td.gridbotright {
  border-right: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  border-bottom: solid windowtext 0.5pt;
  padding: 0in 3pt 0in 3pt;
}
tr.grideven {
  background-color="##FFFFFF";
  color="#000000";
  font-weight: "normal";
  font-size: "12"
}
tr.gridodd {
  background-color="#FFFFFF";
  color="#000000";
  font-weight: "normal";
  font-size: "12"
}
tr.grid {
  background-color: "#FFFFFF";
  color: "#000000";
  font-weight: "bold";
  font-size: "12"
}
table.gridhead {
  background-color: "#FFFFFF";
  color: "#000000";
  font-weight: "bold";
  font-size: "12";
  font-family: "Arial, sans-serif"
}
table.gridbody {
  border-left: solid
}
```

I need to move this inline the table . What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you familiar with gulp, the [gulp-inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-css) module would be your quickest.

Edit: Or you can try the following tools:

https://inliner.cm/

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Answer (score 0):

For emails use inline CSS. Because browser-based email applications, such as Gmail, strip out  and  tags by default, always use inline CSS over embedded CSS.

So just assign it to each element manually in with an attribute `style="yourcssgoesgere"`.

More info for example here: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/